# Testing faulty fibre network

Tags: fiber, netgear

As contractors linked the main comms with 3 sub-comms location with OM3 fibre I configured main switch Netgear GS728TS using three transceivers Netgear AGM731F, configured switches that will be used on it other end ( GS110TP) and then connected everything to fibre patch panel. Well nothing is happening. I tested both cables I am plugging to fibre patch panel - all fine, transivers are fine either.
I got back to contractors but they are quite convinced that all should be fine. Is there any diagnostics, checks, test I can run to check if cabling is flawless ? I dont want to force them to site if there is something tiny and obvious preventing connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can log into the managed Netgear switches you should be able to use the internal utility to get information about the relevant ports.  See Page 256 of the linked [switch software admin manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS728TPS/GS7xxTS_GS7xxTPS-SWA_1Mar12.pdf).

You should be able to get much more detailed information about the relevant ports like their physical status, etc using the management interface from Netgear.  If the fibre cables you mentioned are using the SFP ports you may want to verify that the cables are compatible with all interconnected networking equipment, some may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the manual. Switch back end is showing as off at the moment. The transceivers look like are compatible with OM3 and this is what should be installed. I am really getting confused here and I dont want to act to hard on them if there is fault on my side.

Comment: To clarify, is it possible to do a cable test using the switch management interface?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it might be obvious solution for someone or it might be actually helpful for other. We found solution by dismantling the splice drawer - Tx/Rx runs where connected to wrong ports all that have to be done is to unplug fiber runs inside and swap them around.